# How does one parse a multipart message in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, multipart

I have an MHTML file that I need to extract "sub-files" from. It appears that the .NET Framework 4.5 may have support for this, but I can't figure it out. I imagine it has something to do with the [`System.Net.Http.HttpContent` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.aspx) or one of its subclasses. I *would* show an attempt I have made at this myself, but I can't even find the starting point. I wrote my own (buggy) parser, but there's just too many ifs, ands, and buts with the specification for one mortal to handle alone.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some use of this https://code.google.com/p/dotnetmimer/